# Want to save array values in CSV file into two columns. Currently all values are in one row

Tags: php, csv, for-loop, fputcsv

I am storing one CSV file values into another through PHP.
I want to save `$col_1_values_array` values in one column into CSV file and `$col_2_values_array` into another column. although my code is showing all values into a single row,how can i correct it?

here's my code

```
 $data_file = $ride[$i][0];
 $file_delimiter = ',';

 $csv = new csvCRUD($data_file,$file_delimiter);
 $col_1_values_array=$csv->output_column('C','array');
 $col_2_values_array=$csv->output_column('D','array');
 $c=count($col_1_values_array);
 $line=array();
 $fp = fopen('7654.csv', 'w');
 for($p=0;$p<$c;$p++)
 {
  $line[]=$col_1_values_array[$p];
  $line[]=$col_2_values_array[$p];
  }
  fputcsv($fp,$line);

  fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `fputcsv()` into your loop. That way a new row is created with each iteration. As of right now you're just making one big array which then is added as  one big row.

```
for($p=0;$p<$c;$p++)
{
    $line[]=$col_1_values_array[$p];
    $line[]=$col_2_values_array[$p];
    fputcsv($fp,$line);
}
```

Comment: its showing into two colunms but because of loop previous values also come.hence new values come ahead of previous values.its result shape in csv file is :9.00   31.456

Comment: its showing into two colunms but because of loop previous values also come.hence new values come ahead of previous values.its result shape in csv file is :9.00   31.456                                                                                                                                 .                     9.00   31.456  9.02  31.467                                 .                     9.00   31.456  9.02  31.467  9.04   31.568                                                                                        how to correct it?